# Automate a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-ec2

Im trying to install **Anaconda** on newly created **EC2 instance** using a bash script. While installation, it first asks to press **enter** then read through agreement(which I can skip by pressing q), then type **yes** to accept it. Once it's done, I have to type yes again to add PATH to **.bashrc**. I am trying to automate this but I'm not sure how it should be done. I tried to use **Yes command**, but it didn't work. I found out I can use **expect command** but for this I have to install its package first and It also asks to press some key(which I cannot automate) so I have to find some other way. It would be great if someone can provide some solution.

Comment: Does this help https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html#install-macos-silent

Comment: @DusanBajic Indeed, It did! Thanks man.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Please answer your question based on whatever you figured out and then mark that answer as accepted so people know it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

As *@Dusan Bajic* suggested, I installed Anaconda silently, which doesn't ask for any user input. I simply executed the following commands:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda2-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O anaconda.sh
bash anaconda.sh -b
```

where **b** is: *Batch mode with no PATH modifications to ~/.bashrc. Assumes that you agree to the license agreement. Does not edit the .bashrc or .bash_profile files.*

And then I added the PATH manually to **.bashrc**.

```
echo 'export PATH=/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```